# `cl-incf` returns inconsistent values

Tags: setf

```
(setq ali '())
>>> nil
(cl-incf (alist-get 'a ali 0))
>>> ((a . 1))
(setf (alist-get 'b ali) 0)
>>> ((b . 0) (a . 1))
(cl-incf (alist-get 'b ali 0))
>>> 1
```

As you can see, `cl-incf` returns different kinds of values in the second and the fourth expressions.

`cl-incf` per documentation is supposed to return "the incremented value of PLACE", however as we can see with the key `'a` it returns the whole `ali` structure. If we macroexpand it a few times, it's clear what's happening:

```
(let*
    ((p
      (if
          (and nil
               (not
                (eq nil 'eq)))
          (assoc 'a ali nil)
        (assq 'a ali)))
     (v
      (+
       (if p
           (cdr p)
         0)
       1)))
  (if p
      (setcdr p v)
    (setq ali
          (cons
           (setq p
                 (cons 'a v))
           ali))))
```

The last `setq` is applied to `ali`, so it returns the new value of `ali`.

It seems to be a bug in the alist generalized variable definition.

Am I correct? If so, how to report it?
If not, what's the idiomatic way to work around it, preferably not calling `alist-get` two times?

Comment: Yep, the behavior for the second sexp, `(cl-incf (alist-get 'a ali 0))` looks wrong. Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I think the last part of the expansion should be something like this: `(if p
        (setcdr p v)
      (setq ali (cons (setq p (cons 'a v)) ali))
      v)`.

IOW, after updating `ali` it should return `v`, not `ali`. In all cases it should return `v`.

Comment: I went ahead and filed bug report #[42837](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=42837) for this. Wasn't sure you'd do it, and wanted to get it done. Feel free to chime in there.

Comment: Emacs 27.1's return value is correct, in other words, for your seconds expression, it returns `1` instead of `((a . 1))`. I don't have Emacs 26.3 installed, so I can't test that version.

Comment: @Drew thank you for filing the report, it's okay that you did it.

Comment: @xuchunyang it's good to know that it's fixed in 27.1. My Emacs version is 26.3.

Comment: @Drew I guess, you can write a short answer mentioning `emacs-report-bug` and your report and I'll mark it as a correct answer. Also, the fact that it's apparently fixed in 27.1 which I can't test right now.

Comment: @grepcake: Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the behavior for the second sexp, `(cl-incf (alist-get 'a ali 0))` looks wrong. I think the last part of the expansion should be something like this:

```lisp
(if p
    (setcdr p v)
  (setq ali (cons (setq p (cons 'a v)) ali))
  v)
```

IOW, after updating `ali` it should return `v`, not `ali`. In all cases it should return `v`.

I filed Emacs bug #[42837](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=42837) for this. In the future, you can do it yourself via `report-emacs-bug`.

But it turns out this has already been fixed in Emacs 27.1, which has just been released.